# Swich to light or dark mode on Django?

Tags: python, css, django

How can I make a button that when pressed would change my css href between light.css and dark.css

**I can't use JavaScript.**

Comment: _"I can't use JavaScript."_ Why make things complicated??

Comment: Then you have to submit the form and get your backend to switch it.

Answer (score 1):

In very basic terms you would just change the CSS file depending on whether dark mode is selected or not:

```html
{% if request.user.darkmode %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/dark.css' %}">
{% else %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/light.css' %}">
{% endif %
```

You can track `darkmode` in the session like so:

```py
if request.POST.get('darkmode'):
   request.session['darkmode'] = True
```

You would have to send `darkmode` to the view in a POST request. Because you aren't using javascript, you would likely need a view just for setting darkmode and redirecting to another view.

The other option is to add `darkmode` as a field to the User model so that it's always saved to the current user once it has been set.